# How to write local variable to a file in remote server using Powershell script?

Tags: powershell

On a remote server there is a .BAT file  which uses a .properties file to run.

I am able to run the .BAT file calling the .properties file, but in that .properties file last line is:

```
exportQuery1=SELECT * FROM CI_INFOOBJECTS where SI_ID='123456'.
```

I am modifying that line/SI_ID value manually which actually increasing my effort.

I have tried a few options but am not able to provide the value/entire line from the local powershell commandline which will be written in the .properties file.

So I have to modify the .ps1 every time. I want to pass the entry  with the local powershell command as a variable.

Deleting the old line:

```
Invoke-Command -computername $ServerName -Credential $Cred -ErrorAction stop -ScriptBlock {Set-Content -Path D:\Script\TestFile.txt -Value (get-content -Path D:\Script\TestFile.txt | Select-String -Pattern 'SI_ID' -NotMatch)}
```

Creating the New line at the end of the file:

```
Invoke-Command -computername $ServerName -Credential $Cred -ErrorAction stop -ScriptBlock {add-content D:\Script\TestFile.txt "exportQuery1=SELECT * FROM CI_INFOOBJECTS where SI_ID='abcdef'"}
```

Please help to pass the SI_ID/entire line from the command while executing the script.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a simple parameter and the using statement in a single invoke call?

```
param($SI_ID)

$SB = {
    Set-Content -Path D:\Script\TestFile.txt -Value (get-content -Path D:\Script\TestFile.txt | Select-String -Pattern 'SI_ID' -NotMatch)
    add-content D:\Script\TestFile.txt "exportQuery1=SELECT * FROM CI_INFOOBJECTS where SI_ID='$using:SI_ID'"
}

Invoke-Command -computername $ServerName -Credential $Cred -ErrorAction stop -ScriptBlock $SB
```

then just `.\myscript -SI_ID "abcd"`

Comment: Many thanks Sambardo. This is really helpful. But the only error I am getting is **"A Using variable cannot be retrieved. A Using variable can be used only with Invoke-Command, Start-Job, or InlineScript in the script workflow. When it is used with Invoke-Command, the Using variable is valid only if the script block is invoked on a remote computer."** The deletion part is working perfectly. But add-content part is not working. I have tried few more options but failed. Am I doing something in wrong way.

Comment: Can you post the code you're running to get the error?

Comment: param($SI_ID)
$Username = ''
$Password = ''
$ServerName = ''
$Pass = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $Password -Force
$Cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $Username,$Pass
$SB = {
Set-Content -Path D:\Script\testscript.properties -Value (get-content -Path D:\Script\testscript.properties | Select-String -Pattern 'SI_ID' -NotMatch)
add-content D:\Script\testscript.properties "exportQuery1=SELECT * FROM CI_INFOOBJECTS where SI_ID='$using:SI_ID'"
}
Invoke-Command -computername $ServerName -Credential $Cred -ErrorAction stop -ScriptBlock $SB

Comment: You should add an edit to your question with the code formatted and what issues you are running into now. As a comment this is unreadable.